# Spring Boot Index-Page returns 403 in Docker Container

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot

I've got a Spring Boot Application, with a RequestMapping to / for its Index-Page, I've created an docker image for easy hosting.
If I start the docker container and browse to localhost:8084 (I've exposed Port 3002 and mapped it to 8084) I get "HTTP Error 403 - Not Authorized" instead of redirecting to localhost:8084/user/login.
If I browse to localhost:8084/user/login I'll get the login page. I also set up an Apache with ReverseProxy on the Docker Host but also no difference.
So my Question what is going wrong here? If I start the Application without Docker there is no Problem and I'm redirected fine.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE

VOLUME /tmp
RUN mkdir /deployment
VOLUME /deployment/data

ADD compareTestData.zip /deployment/data/compareTestData/
COPY target/${JAR_FILE} /deployment/app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /deployment/app.jar'

EXPOSE 3002

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/deployment/app.jar"]
```

My IndexController like this (I removed all unnecessary code) :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @RequestMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('index', 'get')")
    public String getIndex(Model model, Principal principal) {
        try {
            return "index";
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

My WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class FormWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("sessionListener")
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionListener> sessionListener() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>(new SessionListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user", "/user/login", "/user/register").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/user/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/user/logout")
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

The logging output as commented by PaulNUK:

```
2018-08-15 12:26:41.563 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Zugriff verweigert
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
        # Stacktrace removed because of character limitation#
2018-08-15 12:26:41.564 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.564 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.564 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2018-08-15 12:26:41.564 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@5e7e4311, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing text/html
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/xhtml+xml
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing image/webp
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith image/webp = false
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing image/apng
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith image/apng = false
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/xml;q=0.9
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xml;q=0.9 = false
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing */*;q=0.8
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Ignoring
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Did not match any media types
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2018-08-15 12:26:41.565 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.566 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2018-08-15 12:26:41.566 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : All requestMatchers returned true
2018-08-15 12:26:41.566 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8084/]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.566 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2018-08-15 12:26:41.566 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2018-08-15 12:26:41.566 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@510c25f5
2018-08-15 12:26:41.566 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2018-08-15 12:26:41.567 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2018-08-15 12:26:41.567 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2bf78a1f
2018-08-15 12:26:41.567 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.567 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.567 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2018-08-15 12:26:41.567 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1412c8a7. A new one will be created.
2018-08-15 12:26:41.567 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.567 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.567 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.567 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logout'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : queryString: both null (property equals)
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : requestURI: arg1=/; arg2=/error (property not equals)
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@3e9b471e: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffdaa08: RemoteIpAddress: 172.17.0.1; SessionId: 9B6893C62D8CE2E2072D343FA21B122C; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2018-08-15 12:26:41.568 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.569 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2018-08-15 12:26:41.570 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.570 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.570 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2018-08-15 12:26:41.570 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2018-08-15 12:26:41.570 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.template.provider.cache' in any property source
2018-08-15 12:26:41.571 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.template.provider.cache' in any property source
2018-08-15 12:26:41.572 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
2018-08-15 12:26:41.573 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'error'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.573 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@49b2a47d] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.573 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@49b2a47d] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.573 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2018-08-15 12:26:41.573 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Closing JPA EntityManager
2018-08-15 12:26:41.574 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2018-08-15 12:26:41.574 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2018-08-15 12:26:41.574 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2018-08-15 12:26:41.574 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2018-08-15 12:26:41.600 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2bf78a1f
2018-08-15 12:26:41.600 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.600 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1412c8a7. A new one will be created.
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/favicon.ico'; against '/logout'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /favicon.ico' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /favicon.ico' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /favicon.ico' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : queryString: both null (property equals)
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : requestURI: arg1=/; arg2=/favicon.ico (property not equals)
2018-08-15 12:26:41.601 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2018-08-15 12:26:41.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@3e9b471e: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffdaa08: RemoteIpAddress: 172.17.0.1; SessionId: 9B6893C62D8CE2E2072D343FA21B122C; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-08-15 12:26:41.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /favicon.ico reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2018-08-15 12:26:41.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/favicon.ico]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/favicon.ico] are [/**/favicon.ico]
2018-08-15 12:26:41.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/favicon.ico] are {}
2018-08-15 12:26:41.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/favicon.ico] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/], class path resource []], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@7cbd9d24]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-08-15 12:26:41.602 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/favicon.ico] is: -1
2018-08-15 12:26:41.604 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@510c25f5
2018-08-15 12:26:41.604 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2018-08-15 12:26:41.607 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-08-15 12:26:41.607 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2018-08-15 12:26:41.609 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2018-08-15 12:26:41.609 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2018-08-15 12:26:41.609 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-3002-exec-7] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2bf78a1f
```

Apache Config on Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName layouter.localhost
  ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/layouter-error_log"
  CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/layouter-access_log" common
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8084/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8084/
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
  ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: set the environment variable logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG when running the docker container and see in the spring logs why it's giving you a 403.

Comment: I've done as you said but I do not see where the Request is failing, maybe you could help me there? I've added the Logging Output to the Question.

Comment: can you post your apache ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse  settings ?

Comment: Yes, of course. But just to mention, the docker container itself has no Apache installed. The Spring Boot App is hosted on port 3002 the Docker image exposes Port 3002 which is mapped to HostPort 8084 on the Host I'm browsing to localhost:8084 so there is no Apache config. But I also set up an Apache on the Host which maps an URL to localhost:8084. Anyway, I've added the Config to the Question. And just to mention I already tried to set server.use-forward-headers=true in Application Properties...

Comment: Thank you very much Paul, I don't know why but it*s working now, without a change to the code or configuration and also without Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a week ago and I was getting the same 403 error in a similar setup with spring boot, front end and back end environment and a reverse proxy. The reason being in my case was that my port 8080 was occupied by another application at the same time and spring was not complaining about it. Instead of sending requests to my server, it was doing it to that application without me knowing, and therefore all connections to my back end were refused.

What resolved my issue was killing that extra process listening on port 8080 and afterwards, my backend started processing all requests sent by the proxy.

So if you came across this similar issue, don't hesitate to verify what apps are listening on your port before changing any configuration on your app.

Hope this help you save time.

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
```