# Spring security works on localhost, but gives '403 Forbidden' in docker on server

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-security, spring-rest

Before implementing Spring Security, I could easily create a docker image on my server and access the REST-API when it ran on my server. Since I implemented the Spring Security, I get a '403 Forbidden' response on every path when I run the docker image on my server (via Jenkins and NGINX).

When I run the application locally, I can access all paths (except for the, by login, restricted ones). E.g. `http://localhost:8080/movies/1` returns the movie with `id` 1 properly.

I followed [this](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) tutorial and tried to adjust most things to my own setup.

This is an example of one of my controllers, the MovieController:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/movies")
public class MovieController {
    final MovieRepository MR;
    public MovieController(MovieRepository MR) {this.MR = MR;}

    @RequestMapping("/all")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Movie> getAllMovies() {
        return MR.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/byId")
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<Movie> getMovieById(@RequestParam int id) {
        return MR.findById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/byTitle")
    @ResponseBody
    public Movie getMovieByTitle(@RequestParam String title) {
        return MR.findByTitle(title);
    }
}
```

The following code is from my WebSecurity class:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/movies/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/chairs/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager())).addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
}
```

This is the SIGN_UP_URL constant used in the WebSecurity class:

```java
public static final String SIGN_UP_URL = "/users/register";
```

As you can see, I should at least be able to visit the `/movies/` paths on my website, but even those are forbidden (on the server).

I am using reverse proxy on my server, the {domain}/api/ routes to port 3001 on my server, which is rerouted to internal port 8080, where the API is running.

I think this is all the information needed for this problem, if you need any more information, please request it in the responses to this post.

Could anybody please tell me why I would get a '403 forbidden' response when I run it in docker, and how I might fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is most probably a CORS issue.

Try adding:

```
http.cors().disable()
```

and check the result.

If it works, then you can try implementing CORS-enabled server.

Comment: Adding `cors().disable()` did not work, still getting 403 on all paths.

I do have [this](https://imgur.com/qSSfBON) set up in a WebConfiguration class.
But I never had any problems with this, since this was set up way before spring security was implemented in the app.

Comment: Commenting out the, in the last comment, mentioned configuration also did not fix it.

Comment: Maybe the port reroute thing is giving this error? Maybe that port you're mentioning is restricted in the dock image itself?

Comment: Another thing, you mention that "E.g. http://localhost:8080/movies/1 returns the movie with id 1 properly.", but your controller has actually the "movies/byId/{ID}" mapping.

Comment: True! But I think Spring itself creates the `movies/{id}` mapping (which would admittedly make mine useless), but a path like `/movies/all` also returns 403

Comment: I think logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG can help

Comment: This is weird, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51855215/spring-boot-index-page-returns-403-in-docker-container) guy had the exactly same problem, but managed to solve it somehow, see the comments of the question.

Comment: Yeah! Saw that thread, but the "didn't change any code or configuration" bit didn't really make it any clearer as to what was thu actual problem hahah

I will try the DEBUG setting first thing in the morning. Thanks for trying to help me out here! :)